# Доступ к файлам android

Tags: android, python

Здравствуйте, вопрос следующий: Какие привелегии есть у приложения, которое является "Администратором устройства". Просто есть задача получить содержимое каталога другого приложения ( /data/data/ ... ). Возможно ли это сделать ( на устройстве нету рута ). Если да, то как это реализовать на Python ? Большее спасибо

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под понятием приложение "Администратор устройства"?

Comment: Это приложения, который в : Настройки->безопасность->администраторы устройств